# AMP form select How to get the value of the data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

**Hello!**

I'm using amp-bind method. At the AMP form I track select event change. Next, I change the value of the page element.

This all works fine, for example:

```html
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

<form method="post" action-xhr="#">
  <select name="items-select" on="change:AMP.setState({item: event.value})">
    <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
    <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="Cookies">Cookies</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p [text]="'Field Value: ' + item">Field Value: secret</p>
```

My question concerns the following: How do I read the values of the data attribute?

For example here:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

<form method="post" action-xhr="#">
  <select name="items-select" on="change:AMP.setState({item: event.value})">
    <option data-id="1" data-name="item-4453" data-discount="0" value="Milk">Milk</option>
    <option data-id="2" data-name="item-4454" data-discount="1" value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option data-id="3" data-name="item-4455" data-discount="1" value="Cookies">Cookies</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**How do I get the value of all the data- for the selected item?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```html
        <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
        
        <form method="post" action-xhr="#">
          <select name="items-select" on="change:AMP.setState({item: event.value})">
            <option value="1,Milk">Milk</option>
            <option value="2,Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
            <option value="3,Cookies">Cookies</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        
        <p [text]="'Field Value: ' + item.split(',')[0] + ' Field Name: ' + item.split(',')[1]">Field Value: 1 Field Name: Milk</p>
```

EDIT: It turns out what you need to do is much simpler than using `<amp-selector>`. Currently, there is no possible way to set data from multiple attributes. However, could use comma `,`
 or semicolon `;` delimited string (whichever suits you)

Comment: Hey @adnanyousafch!, thanks for your reply. Can I use the data attribute? For example: `<div option="1" data-id="1" data-name="item-1" data-discount="0" >Milk</option>` I need to read many values, based on these values, to change the elements on the page. I will supplement my question. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I was  unable to find a way to add more than one thing (a json object) through `option` and option is the only way to do it. What I ended up doing is setting comma delimited values e.g. `option="{{code}},{{name}},{{countryName}}"` then using them with help of array split in binds `[value]="obj ? obj.split(',')[1] + ', ' + obj.split(',')[2] + ' (' + obj.split(',')[0] + ')' : ''"`. Hope you can use this workaround.

Comment: So for your case it would be `<div option="1,item-1">Milk</option>` and then using it as `<p [text]="'Field Value: ' + item.split(',')[0]">Field Value: secret</p>`

Comment: It will be better if you complete your code snippet response, which you can run. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov I have modified my answer with runnable/working code snippet. Hope that helps.